# Convert file format from .bz2 to gz on Mac

Tags: pipe, gunzip

I have lots of bunzip2 compressed files that I would like to convert to .gz. I tried the following using a pipe, but it does not work. I guess the reason is gzip does not know what files to zip.

```
bunzip2 test.txt.bz2 | gzip
```

any way to use a pipe for connecting `bunzip2` and `gzip` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running gzip with no parameters, it expects its output to be piped into a file:

```
bzcat test.txt.bz2 | gzip -c - >test.txt.gz
```

For completeness, I have included the following (although they are both optional when input is from standard input and output is redirected or sent to another pipe):

- -c option (Write output on standard output)
- a file name of - (If no files are specified, or if a file name is "-", the standard input is compressed to the standard output.)

Comment: I suggest you add a little explanation about your solution. Code-only solutions are (sometimes) good, but code+explanation answers are (almost always) better

Comment: Explanation added. Thank you for the advice. :)